# PHP form will not store text in database field $_POST method

Tags: php, html

I am trying to use the POST method to try and add text into my database field. The database field I am specifically talking about is called ProductVariantHTML. Some reason it is not posting the data into my database.

**This is the textarea in my form**

```
<tr>
    <td><label for="product-variant-html-description">Variant HTML Description:</label></td>
    <td><textarea id="product-variant-html-description" name="ProductVariantHTML" maxlength=""><?=htmlspecialchars($productVariantHTML)?></textarea></td>
    <td><span class="input-help"></span></td>
</tr>
```

**This is the ProductVariant Class**

```
<?php
class ProductVariant
{
    // Attributes
    private $_Con;
    private $_productVariantID;
    private $_productID;
    private $_SKU;
    private $_MPN;
    private $_barcode;
    private $_price;
    private $_salePrice;
    private $_finalPrice;
    private $_stock;
    private $_length;
    private $_height;
    private $_width;
    private $_weight;
    private $_leadTimeFrom;
    private $_leadTimeTo;
    private $_soldCount;
    private $_createdDate;
//Nathan Added 2017
    private $_productVariantHTML;

//Nathan Added 2017
    public function __construct(MySQLi $Con = NULL, $productVariantID = NULL, $productID = NULL, $SKU = NULL, $MPN = NULL, $barcode = NULL, $price = NULL, $salePrice = NULL, $finalPrice = NULL, $stock = NULL, $length = NULL, $height = NULL, $width = NULL, $weight = NULL, $leadTimeFrom = NULL, $leadTimeTo = NULL, $soldCount = NULL, $createdDate = NULL, $productVariantHTML = NULL)
    {
        $this->_Con = $Con;
        $this->_productVariantID = $productVariantID;
        $this->_productID = $productID;
        $this->_SKU = $SKU;
        $this->_MPN = $MPN;
        $this->_barcode = $barcode;
        $this->_price = $price;
        $this->_salePrice = $salePrice;
        $this->_finalPrice = $finalPrice;
        $this->_stock = $stock;
        $this->_length = $length;
        $this->_height = $height;
        $this->_width = $width;
        $this->_weight = $weight;
        $this->_leadTimeFrom = $leadTimeFrom;
        $this->_leadTimeTo = $leadTimeTo;
        $this->_soldCount = $soldCount;
        $this->_createdDate = $createdDate;
//Nathan Added 2017
        $this->_productVariantHTML = $productVariantHTML;
    }

    // Properties Get
    public function GetProductVariantID() { return $this->_productVariantID; }
    public function GetProductID() { return $this->_productID; }
    public function GetSKU() { return $this->_SKU; }
    public function GetMPN() { return $this->_MPN; }
    public function GetBarcode() { return $this->_barcode; }
    public function GetPrice() { return $this->_price; }
    public function GetSalePrice() { return $this->_salePrice; }
    public function GetFinalPrice() { return $this->_finalPrice; }
    public function GetStock() { return $this->_stock; }
    public function GetLength() { return $this->_length; }
    public function GetHeight() { return $this->_height; }
    public function GetWidth() { return $this->_width; }
    public function GetWeight() { return $this->_weight; }
    public function GetLeadTimeFrom() { return $this->_leadTimeFrom; }
    public function GetLeadTimeTo() { return $this->_leadTimeTo; }
    public function GetSoldCount() { return $this->_soldCount; }
    public function GetCreatedDate() { return $this->_createdDate; }
//Nathan Added 2017
    public function GetProductVariantHTML() { return $this->_productVariantHTML; }

    // Properties Set
    public function SetProductVariantID($v) { $this->_productVariantID = $v; }
    public function SetProductID($v) { $this->_productID = $v; }
    public function SetSKU($v) { $this->_SKU = $v; }
    public function SetMPN($v) { $this->_MPN = $v; }
    public function SetBarcode($v) { $this->_barcode = $v; }
    public function SetPrice($v) { $this->_price = $v; }
    public function SetSalePrice($v) { $this->_salePrice = $v; }
    public function SetFinalPrice($v) { $this->_finalPrice = $v; }
    public function SetStock($v) { $this->_stock = $v; }
    public function SetLength($v) { $this->_length = $v; }
    public function SetHeight($v) { $this->_height = $v; }
    public function SetWidth($v) { $this->_width = $v; }
    public function SetWeight($v) { $this->_weight = $v; }
    public function SetLeadTimeFrom($v) { $this->_leadTimeFrom = $v; }
    public function SetLeadTimeTo($v) { $this->_leadTimeTo = $v; }
    public function SetSoldCount($v) { $this->_soldCount = $v; }
    public function SetCreatedDate($v) { $this->_createdDate = $v; }
//Nathan Added 2017
    public function SetProductVariantHTML($v) { $this->_productVariantHTML = $v; }
    public function FillProductVariantFromDBByProductID($productID)
    {
        $productID = $this->_Con->real_escape_string($productID);
        $variantSQL = $this->_Con->query("SELECT ProductVariantID, ProductID, SKU FROM product_variant WHERE ProductID = $productID");

        if ($variantSQL == TRUE && $variantSQL->num_rows > 0) {
            while ($variantRow = $variantSQL->fetch_assoc()) {
                $ProductVariants[] = new self(NULL, (int)$variantRow['ProductVariantID'], (int)$variantRow['ProductID'], $variantRow['SKU']);
            }
            return $ProductVariants;
        }
        else {
            return FALSE;
        }
    }

    public function FillProductVariantFromDBByProductVariantID($productVariantID)
    {
        $productVariantID = $this->_Con->real_escape_string($productVariantID);
        $variantSQL = $this->_Con->query("SELECT * FROM product_variant WHERE ProductVariantID = $productVariantID");

        if ($variantSQL == TRUE && $variantSQL->num_rows > 0) {
            $variantRow = $variantSQL->fetch_assoc();
            $this->_productVariantID = (int)$variantRow['ProductVariantID'];
            $this->_productID = (int)$variantRow['ProductID'];
            $this->_SKU = $variantRow['SKU'];
            $this->_MPN = $variantRow['MPN'];
            $this->_barcode = $variantRow['Barcode'];
            $this->_price = (float)$variantRow['Price'];
            $this->_salePrice = ($variantRow['SalePrice'] == NULL) ? NULL : (float)$variantRow['SalePrice'];
            $this->_finalPrice = (float)$variantRow['FinalPrice'];
            $this->_stock = (int)$variantRow['Stock'];
            $this->_length = ($variantRow['Length'] == NULL) ? NULL : (float)$variantRow['Length'];
            $this->_height = ($variantRow['Height'] == NULL) ? NULL : (float)$variantRow['Height'];
            $this->_width = ($variantRow['Width'] == NULL) ? NULL : (float)$variantRow['Width'];
            $this->_weight = ($variantRow['Weight'] == NULL) ? NULL : (float)$variantRow['Weight'];
            $this->_leadTimeFrom = (int)$variantRow['LeadTimeFrom'];
            $this->_leadTimeTo = (int)$variantRow['LeadTimeTo'];
//Nathan Added 2017
            $this->_productVariantHTML = $variantRow['ProductVariantHTML'];

            return TRUE;
        }
        else {
            return FALSE;
        }
    }

    // Create variant
    public function CreateVariant($productID, $SKU, $MPN, $barcode, $price, $stock)
    {
        // Assign variables
        $Con = $this->_Con;
        $productID = $Con->real_escape_string($productID);
        $SKU = $Con->real_escape_string(trim($SKU));
        if (empty($MPN)) {
            $MPN = 'NULL';
        } else {
            $MPN = "'" . $Con->real_escape_string(trim($MPN)) . "'";
        }
        if (empty($barcode)) {
            $barcode = 'NULL';
        } else {
            $barcode = "'" . $Con->real_escape_string(trim($barcode)) . "'";
        }
        $price = $Con->real_escape_string($price);
        $finalPrice = $price;
        $stock = $Con->real_escape_string($stock);

        // Turn off autocommit
        $Con->autocommit(FALSE);
        $Con->query('BEGIN');

        $variantSQL = $Con->query("INSERT INTO product_variant (ProductID, SKU, MPN, Barcode, Price, FinalPrice, Stock, LeadTimeFrom, LeadTimeTo)
        VALUES ($productID, '$SKU', $MPN, $barcode, $price, $finalPrice, $stock, 1, 2)");

        // Update productVariantID
        $productVariantID = $Con->insert_id;
        $this->_productVariantID = $productVariantID;

        $detailSQL = $Con->query("INSERT INTO product_detail (ProductVariantID)
        VALUES ($productVariantID)");

        if ($variantSQL == TRUE && $detailSQL == TRUE) {
            // Commit the data, turn autocommit on
            $Con->commit(); 
            $Con->autocommit(TRUE); 
            return TRUE;
        }
        else {
            // If error inputting ANY data, rollback
            $Con->rollback();
            $Con->autocommit(TRUE);
            return FALSE;
        }
    }

    // Create multi variant
    public function CreateMultiVariant($variant, $productID, $SKU, $MPN, $barcode, $price, $stock, $variantStr)
    {
        // Assign variables
        $Con = $this->_Con;
        $productID = $Con->real_escape_string($productID);
        $success = TRUE;

        // Turn off autocommit
        $Con->autocommit(FALSE);
        $Con->query('BEGIN');

        // Loop through variant types and values
        foreach ($variant as $key => $val)
        {
            // Get variant type and insert into database
            $dbVariant = $Con->real_escape_string($key);
            $variantSQL = $Con->query("INSERT INTO variant (Variant)
            VALUES ('$dbVariant')");

            if ($success == TRUE && $variantSQL == TRUE)
            {
                $variantID = $Con->insert_id;

                // Loop through each variant type values
                foreach ($val as $v)
                {
                    $dbVariantValue = $Con->real_escape_string($v);
                    $variantValueSQL = $Con->query("INSERT INTO variant_value (VariantID, VariantValue)
                    VALUES ($variantID, '$dbVariantValue')");

                    if ($variantValueSQL == TRUE) {
                        $variantIDLink[$v] = $Con->insert_id;
                    }
                    else {
                        $success = FALSE;
                        break;
                    }
                }
            }
            else
            {
                $success = FALSE;
                break;
            }
        }

        if ($success == TRUE)
        {
            for ($i = 0; isset($SKU[$i]); $i++)
            {
                $dbSKU = $Con->real_escape_string(trim($SKU[$i]));
                if (empty($MPN[$i])) {
                    $dbMPN = 'NULL';
                } else {
                    $dbMPN = "'" . $Con->real_escape_string(trim($MPN[$i])) . "'";
                }
                if (empty($barcode[$i])) {
                    $dbBarcode = 'NULL';
                } else {
                    $dbBarcode = "'" . $Con->real_escape_string(trim($barcode[$i])) . "'";
                }
                $dbPrice = $Con->real_escape_string($price[$i]);
                $dbFinalPrice = $dbPrice;
                $dbStock = $Con->real_escape_string($stock[$i]);

                // SQL INSERT for Product Variant
                $pVariantSQL = $Con->query("INSERT INTO product_variant (ProductID, SKU, MPN, Barcode, Price, FinalPrice, Stock, LeadTimeFrom, LeadTimeTo)
                VALUES ($productID, '$dbSKU', $dbMPN, $dbBarcode, $dbPrice, $dbFinalPrice, $dbStock, 1, 2)");
                $productVariantID = $Con->insert_id;
                $this->_productVariantID = $productVariantID;

                $dbVariantStrArray = explode('|', $variantStr[$i]);

                foreach ($dbVariantStrArray as $dbVariantStr)
                {
                    // Get ID of variant type
                    $dbVariantID = $variantIDLink[$dbVariantStr];

                    // SQL INSERT for Product Detail
                    $pDetailSQL = $Con->query("INSERT INTO product_detail (ProductVariantID, VariantValueID)
                    VALUES ($productVariantID, $dbVariantID)");

                    if ($pDetailSQL != TRUE) {
                        $success = FALSE;
                        break;
                    }
                }

                if ($success == FALSE || $pVariantSQL == FALSE || $variantSQL == FALSE || $variantValueSQL == FALSE || $pDetailSQL == FALSE) {
                    $success = FALSE;
                    break;
                }
            }
        }

        if ($success == TRUE) {
            // Commit the data, turn autocommit on
            $Con->commit(); 
            $Con->autocommit(TRUE); 
            return TRUE;
        }
        else {
            // If error inputting ANY data, rollback
            $Con->rollback();
            $Con->autocommit(TRUE);
            return FALSE;
        }
    }

    public function UpdatedProductVariant($productVariantID, $SKU, $MPN, $barcode, $price, $salePrice, $stock, $length, $height, $width, $weight, $leadTimeFrom, $leadTimeTo, $productVariantHTML)
    {
        $productVariantID = $this->_Con->real_escape_string($productVariantID);
        $SKU = $this->_Con->real_escape_string($SKU);
        $MPN = $this->_Con->real_escape_string($MPN);
        if (empty($barcode)) {
            $barcode = 'NULL';
        } else {
            $barcode = "'" . $this->_Con->real_escape_string($barcode) . "'";
        }
        $price = $this->_Con->real_escape_string($price);
        if (empty($salePrice)) {
            $salePrice = 'NULL';
            $finalPrice = $price;
        } else {
            $salePrice = $this->_Con->real_escape_string($salePrice);
            $finalPrice = $salePrice;
        }
        $stock = $this->_Con->real_escape_string($stock);
        if (empty($length)) {
            $length = 'NULL';
        } else {
            $length = $this->_Con->real_escape_string($length);
        }
        if (empty($height)) {
            $height = 'NULL';
        } else {
            $height = $this->_Con->real_escape_string($height);
        }
        if (empty($width)) {
            $width = 'NULL';
        } else {
            $width = $this->_Con->real_escape_string($width);
        }
        if (empty($weight)) {
            $weight = 'NULL';
        } else {
            $weight = $this->_Con->real_escape_string($weight);
        }
        if (empty($productVariantHTML)) {
            $productVariantHTML = 'NULL';
        } else {
            $productVariantHTML = $this->_Con->real_escape_string($productVariantHTML);
        }

        $leadTimeFrom = $this->_Con->real_escape_string($leadTimeFrom);
        $leadTimeTo = $this->_Con->real_escape_string($leadTimeTo);

        $variantSQL = $this->_Con->query("UPDATE product_variant SET SKU = '$SKU', MPN = '$MPN', Barcode = $barcode, Price = $price, SalePrice = $salePrice, FinalPrice = $finalPrice, Stock = $stock, Length = $length, Height = $height, Width = $width, Weight = $weight, LeadTimeFrom = $leadTimeFrom, LeadTimeTo = $leadTimeTo, ProductVariantHTML = $productVariantHTML WHERE ProductVariantID = $productVariantID");

        if ($variantSQL == TRUE) {
            return TRUE;
        }
        else {
            return FALSE;
        }
    }

    // Delete variant
    public function DeleteVariant()
    {
        // Assign variables
        $Con = $this->_Con;
        $productVariantID = $this->_productVariantID;

        $deleteSQL = $Con->query("DELETE FROM product_variant WHERE ProductVariantID = $productVariantID");

        if ($deleteSQL == TRUE) {
            return TRUE;
        }
        else {
            return FALSE;
        }
    }

    // Destructor
    public function __destruct()
    {
    }
}
?>
```

**This is the edit-product-variants.php**

```
<?php
include ('includes/site-define.php');
include ('includes/connection-open.php');
include ('includes/checks.php');
$metaTitle = 'Edit Product Variant';
$ConsoleMessage = new ConsoleMessage();
$productVariantID = (isset($_GET['product_variant_id'])) ? $_GET['product_variant_id'] : NULL;
$productID = NULL;
$SKU = NULL;
$MPN = NULL;
$barcode = NULL;
$price = NULL;
$salePrice = NULL;
$finalPrice = NULL;
$stock = NULL;
$length = NULL;
$height = NULL;
$width = NULL;
$weight = NULL;
$leadTimeFrom = NULL;
$leadTimeTo = NULL;
$soldCount = NULL;
$createdDate = NULL;
//Nathan 2017
$productVariantHTML = NULL;

$ProductVariant = new ProductVariant($Con);
$ProductVariant->FillProductVariantFromDBByProductVariantID($productVariantID);
$productVariantID = $ProductVariant->GetProductVariantID();
$productID = $ProductVariant->GetProductID();
$SKU = $ProductVariant->GetSKU();
$MPN = $ProductVariant->GetMPN();
$barcode = $ProductVariant->GetBarcode();
$price = $ProductVariant->GetPrice();
$salePrice = $ProductVariant->GetSalePrice();
$stock = $ProductVariant->GetStock();
$length = $ProductVariant->GetLength();
$height = $ProductVariant->GetHeight();
$width = $ProductVariant->GetWidth();
$weight = $ProductVariant->GetWeight();
$leadTimeFrom = $ProductVariant->GetLeadTimeFrom();
$leadTimeTo = $ProductVariant->GetLeadTimeTo();
//Nathan 2017
$productVariantHTML = $ProductVariant->GetProductVariantHTML();

if (isset($_POST['Save']))
{
    $SKU = $_POST['SKU'];
    $MPN = $_POST['MPN'];
    $barcode = $_POST['Barcode'];
    $price = $_POST['Price'];
    $salePrice = $_POST['SalePrice'];
    $stock = (isset($_POST['Stock'])) ? 1 : 0;
    $length = $_POST['Length'];
    $height = $_POST['Height'];
    $width = $_POST['Width'];
    $weight = $_POST['Weight'];
    $leadTimeFrom = $_POST['LeadTimeFrom'];
    $leadTimeTo = $_POST['LeadTimeTo'];
//Nathan 2017
    $productVariantHTML = $_POST['ProductVariantHTML'];

    if (empty($SKU) || strlen($SKU) > 100) {
        $ConsoleMessage->AddError('SKU', NULL);
    }
    if (empty($MPN) || strlen($MPN) > 100) {
        $ConsoleMessage->AddError('MPN', NULL);
    }
    if (strlen($barcode) > 100) {
        $ConsoleMessage->AddError('Barcode', NULL);
    }
    if (empty($price) || !is_numeric($price)) {
        $ConsoleMessage->AddError('Price', NULL);
    }
    if (!empty($salePrice)) {
        if (!is_numeric($salePrice)) {
            $ConsoleMessage->AddError('Sale Price', NULL);
        }
    }
    if (!empty($length)) {
        if (!is_numeric($length)) {
            $ConsoleMessage->AddError('Length', NULL);
        }
    }
    if (!empty($height)) {
        if (!is_numeric($height)) {
            $ConsoleMessage->AddError('Height', NULL);
        }
    }
    if (!empty($width)) {
        if (!is_numeric($width)) {
            $ConsoleMessage->AddError('Width', NULL);
        }
    }
    if (!empty($weight)) {
        if (!is_numeric($weight)) {
            $ConsoleMessage->AddError('Weight', NULL);
        }
    }
    if (empty($leadTimeFrom) || !is_numeric($leadTimeFrom)) {
        $ConsoleMessage->AddError('Lead Time From', NULL);
    }
    if (empty($leadTimeTo) || !is_numeric($leadTimeTo)) {
        $ConsoleMessage->AddError('Lead Time To', NULL);
    }

    if ($ConsoleMessage->GetErrorCount() === 0) {
        $UpdatedProductVariant = new ProductVariant($Con);
        $updatedProductVariant = $UpdatedProductVariant->UpdatedProductVariant($productVariantID, $SKU, $MPN, $barcode, $price, $salePrice, $stock, $length, $height, $width, $weight, $leadTimeFrom, $leadTimeTo, $productVariantHTML);

        if ($updatedProductVariant == TRUE) {
            header("Location: product-variants.php?product_id=$productID");
            exit();
        }
        else {
            $ConsoleMessage->AddError('Updating Product Variant', NULL);
        }
    }
}
?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title><?=$metaTitle . ' | ' . SITE_NAME?></title>
<?php include ('includes/header-tags.php'); ?>
</head>
<body>
<div id="wrapper">
    <?php
    // Print header
    $HeaderMenu = new HeaderMenu();
    $HeaderMenu->PrintHeader();
    ?>
    <div id="main">
        <div class="h-wrapper">
            <h1>Edit Product Variant</h1>
            <div class="menu-bar">
            </div>
        </div>
        <?php $ConsoleMessage->PrintMessages(); ?>
        <form id="form" method="post" action="">
            <table class="input-table" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0">
                <tr>
                    <th colspan="3">Product Variant Details</th>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td><label for="sku">SKU:</label></td>
                    <td><input type="text" id="sku" size="10" name="SKU" value="<?=htmlspecialchars($SKU)?>" maxlength=""></td>
                    <td><span class="input-help"></span></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td><label for="mpn">MPN:</label></td>
                    <td><input type="text" id="mpn" size="10" name="MPN" value="<?=htmlspecialchars($MPN)?>" maxlength="" /></td>
                    <td><span class="input-help"></span></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td><label for="barcode">Barcode:</label></td>
                    <td><input type="text" id="barcode" size="10" name="Barcode" value="<?=htmlspecialchars($barcode)?>" maxlength="" /></td>
                    <td><span class="input-help"></span></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td><label for="price">Price:</label></td>
                    <td><input type="text" id="price" size="10" name="Price" value="<?=htmlspecialchars($price)?>" maxlength=""></td>
                    <td><span class="input-help"></span></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td><label for="sale-price">Sale Price:</label></td>
                    <td><input type="text" id="sale-price" size="10" name="SalePrice" value="<?=htmlspecialchars($salePrice)?>" maxlength=""></td>
                    <td><span class="input-help"></span></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td><label for="stock">Stock:</label></td>
                    <td>
                    <input type="checkbox" id="stock" name="Stock" <?php if ($stock == 1) { echo 'checked="checked"'; } ?> />
                    </td>
                    <td><span class="input-help"></span></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td><label for="length">Length:</label></td>
                    <td><input type="text" id="length" size="10" name="Length" value="<?=htmlspecialchars($length)?>" maxlength=""></td>
                    <td><span class="input-help"></span></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td><label for="height">Height:</label></td>
                    <td><input type="text" id="height" size="10" name="Height" value="<?=htmlspecialchars($height)?>" maxlength=""></td>
                    <td><span class="input-help"></span></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td><label for="width">Width:</label></td>
                    <td><input type="text" id="width" size="10" name="Width" value="<?=htmlspecialchars($width)?>" maxlength=""></td>
                    <td><span class="input-help"></span></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td><label for="weight">Weight:</label></td>
                    <td><input type="text" id="weight" size="10" name="Weight" value="<?=htmlspecialchars($weight)?>" maxlength=""></td>
                    <td><span class="input-help"></span></td>
                </tr>
<!--Nathan 2017-->
                <tr>
                    <td><label for="product-variant-html-description">Variant HTML Description:</label></td>
                    <td><textarea id="product-variant-html-description" name="ProductVariantHTML" maxlength=""><?=htmlspecialchars($productVariantHTML)?></textarea></td>
                    <td><span class="input-help"></span></td>
                </tr>

                <tr>
                    <td><label for="lead-time-from">Lead Time:</label></td>
                    <td>
                        <input type="text" id="lead-time-from" size="5" name="LeadTimeFrom" value="<?=htmlspecialchars($leadTimeFrom)?>" maxlength=""> to 
                        <input type="text" id="lead-time-to" size="5" name="LeadTimeTo" value="<?=htmlspecialchars($leadTimeTo)?>" maxlength="">
                    </td>
                    <td><span class="input-help"></span></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td colspan="3">
                        <button id="proceed-btn" type="submit" name="Save">Save</button>
                        <img class="btn-load-left" src="images/btn-load.gif">
                    </td>
                </tr>
            </table>
        </form>
    </div>
    <div style="clear:both;"></div>
</div>
<?php include('includes/footer.php') ?>
</body>
</html>
<?php include ('includes/connection-close.php'); ?>
```

**Error Message**

[image: Error]

Comment: Is there a `<form>` in the HTML somewhere?

Comment: Do all the other columns get updated?

Comment: Could you please post the entire HTML code?

Comment: It might be useful to see the code for your `ProductVariant` class

Comment: Just edited above to show product variant class and my edit-product-variant.php has the <form>

Comment: If you use Mozilla check this link out https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Tools/Network_Monitor you should use `Network Monitoring` so you can always check what is beeing send trough your `POST`.

Comment: Your script is at risk of [SQL Injection Attack](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-can-i-prevent-sql-injection-in-php)
Have a look at what happened to [Little Bobby Tables](http://bobby-tables.com/) Even
[if you are escaping inputs, its not safe!](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5741187/sql-injection-that-gets-around-mysql-real-escape-string)
Use [prepared parameterized statements](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php)

Comment: Not a lot of error database access checking going on in that whole set of code

Comment: Add `ini_set('display_errors', 1); ini_set('log_errors',1); error_reporting(E_ALL); mysqli_report(MYSQLI_REPORT_ERROR | MYSQLI_REPORT_STRICT);` to the top of your script. This will force any `mysqli_` errors to
generate an Exception that you cannot miss or ignore.

Comment: @RiggsFolly I added what you said and now have the error message in the image above

Comment: So now you know what you are looking for. Read the message

Comment: @RiggsFolly Sorry I am not strong in PHP, that is why I am trying to learn and figure out problems. Can you see what the error is? I cannot figure this out. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the SQL statement which starts with ""UPDATE product_variant SET SKU...":

```
ProductVariantHTML = $productVariantHTML
```

should be

```
ProductVariantHTML = '$productVariantHTML'
```

I would guess that $productVariantHTML is not a numeric value, nor is it intended to represent another column in the table. Therefore it needs quotes around it. Otherwise, since you made that variable "nathan", it will try to set the value of the ProductVariantHTML column to the value of a column called nathan, because the SQL interpreter treats it literally, not as a string of data.

NB. As others have said in the comments, you could have avoided this kind of syntax error by using proper parameterised queries in the first place, rather than brittle string concatenation. Doing this will also protect you much better against the very real dangers of SQL Injection attacks. Your data is open to being corrupted, deleted or leaked to anyone with the relatively mundane skills needed to manipulate it.